# How to select and return just the inner objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to retrive just the responses from a single form of the document below, I'm using pymongo, so I'm using the `.find()` method.

Every query I do Al other fields are returned too, So I'm confused about which parameters I need to use.

It's strange because whe I try to use:

```py
pprint(list(collection.find(
    {'forms.id': "33b66684-24a9-4a45-a12f-27a330152ac8"}, {'forms': 1, '_id': 1}
)))
```

It returns two forms instead of one.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6283a32ab85dce6cc4869bb9"),
        "company": "turivius",
        "forms": [
            {
                "current_version": 0,
                "history": [
                    {
                        "content": [
                            {
                                "field_id": 1,
                                "helperText": "qualquer arquivo",
                                "type": "file",
                            }
                        ],
                        "layout": [
                            {"h": 50, "id": 1, "type": "file", "w": 100, "x": 0, "y": 1}
                        ],
                        "responses": [
                            {
                                "client_id": 100,
                                "response_date": datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 17, 3, 0),
                                "values": [
                                    {"field_id": 0, "value": "um texto"},
                                    {"field_id": 1, "value": "ICIwIn0="},
                                ],
                            }
                        ],
                        "version": 0,
                    }
                ],
                "id": "33b66684-24a9-4a45-a12f-27a330152ac8",
                "is_active": True,
            },
            {
                "current_version": 0,
                "history": [],
                "id": "fa2eb9a1-c7c4-4b64-b682-7f51658bc4ab",
                "is_active": True,
                "name": "Vrau",
            },
        ],
        "user_id": "1",
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("6283f19f066cf68667a9327d"),
        "company": "turivius",
        "forms": [],
        "user_id": "-1",
    },
]
```

After do the query, I want to return it:

```
[
    {
        "client_id": 100,
        "response_date": datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 17, 3, 0),
        "values": [
            {"field_id": 0, "value": "um texto"},
            {"field_id": 1, "value": "ICIwIn0="},
        ],
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with [`$`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#mongodb-projection-proj.-) operator for `forms` field.

```
db.collection.find({
  "forms.id": "33b66684-24a9-4a45-a12f-27a330152ac8"
},
{
  "forms.$": 1,
  "_id": 1
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vmAVQQoYpX-)

Comment: Nice, It works to return the form, but what about the responses inside the history form? I'll update the question to show what result I expect

Comment: Sorry not Python developer. But after you get the data from MongoDb, you work the extraction part something like: result[0].forms[0].history[0].responses